# CAT on same file from multiple thread fails

Tags: bash, shell

```
    XML_OUTPUT=${WORK_DIR}/xml.txt
    errCode=`cat ${XML_OUTPUT} | grep ERR_CODES | cut -d "=" -f2`
    accesslog_filterMap=`cat ${XML_OUTPUT} | grep ACCESS_LOG_FM_VALUE | cut -d "=" -f2`
    sec_filterMap=`cat ${XML_OUTPUT} | grep SECURITY_FM_VALUE | cut -d "=" -f2`
    instrumentation_filterMap=`cat ${XML_OUTPUT} | grep INSTRUMENTATION_FM_VALUE | cut -d "=" -f2`
    serverhealthcheck_filterMap=`cat ${XML_OUTPUT} | grep SERVER_HEALTH_CHECK_FM_VALUE | cut -d "=" -f2`
```

xml.txt content

```
ERR_CODES=400 401 403 404 408 413 414 500 505 java.lang.Throwable
INSTRUMENTATION_FM_VALUE=TRUE
ACCESS_LOG_FM_VALUE=TRUE
SECURITY_FM_VALUE=TRUE
SERVER_HEALTH_CHECK_FM_VALUE=TRUE
```

When i run this script from multiple threads its not gives always the same result. Sometimes it(cat) returns empty String . How to handle this for multi thread environment ?

Comment: Why are you using `cat`?  `grep` takes the input filename as a parameter.

Comment: it is hard to tell without knowing what does a thread do.  However some comments: 1) useless use of cat 2) if each thread has same `WORK_DIR`, the result would be always same, take this script out of your thread processing. 3) does your thread write to the file too? then you need a file lock.